# Converting NSData to NSArray returns null / error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm trying to convert NSData from an external JSON file into NSArray to display it in a UITableView object.

This returns null:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/json.php"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseArray);
```

This returns `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive`:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/json.php"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
    NSArray *responseArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:response];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseArray);
```

My JSON formats like this:

```
["The Savoy", "London"]["The Ritz", "London"]["Hilton", "New York"]["Marriott", "San Francisco"]
```

I have a feeling it's my JSON formatting causing the problem, but I'm not sure...

**Edit**

Thanks very much for your replies. My JSON and error handling now look like this but I'm getting the same null response:

```
[{"name":"The Savoy", "city":"London}]
[{"name":"The Ritz", "city":"London}]
[{"name":"Hilton", "city":"New York}]
[{"name":"Marriott", "city":"San Francisco}]
```

Objective-C:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", responseArray);
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. If you want an array of array you need to add one set of square brackets around the whole thing.

Comment: Would it be valid if I just had a single array with those values in? That's what I originally tried and it didn't work.

Comment: BTW - you should make use of the error parameter in the call to `JSONObjectWithData` so you can find out what the actual problem is.

Comment: Please, please, please go to json.org and spend *5 minutes* studying the JSON syntax.  Then you will understand the error of your ways.

Comment: @Sebastian Please see the answer by Wojtek and take the advice of Hot Licks. Learn the syntax and you save yourself countless hours of lost effort. And you still have made use of the `error` parameter.

Comment: The reason you're still getting an error, is because its still not valid JSON.  Its 4 separate JSON arrays, not an array of 4 objects as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is wrong - instead of

```
["The Savoy", "London"]["The Ritz", "London"]["Hilton", "New York"]["Marriott", "San Francisco"]
```

use

```
[["The Savoy", "London"],["The Ritz", "London"],["Hilton", "New York"],["Marriott", "San Francisco"]]
```

Comment: better `[["hotel_name":"The Savoy", "hotel_location":"London"],…]` if you can change the server.